# Hibernate 5.x delete record based on partial composite id?

Tags: java, hql, hibernate-5.x

I have an embedded composite key that consist of two column

```
@Embeddable
public static class PK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4049628068378058196L;

    @Column(name="colA", length=32, nullable=false)
    private String colA;

    @Column(name = "colB", length=32, nullable=false)
    private String colB;

   //constructors/getters/setters
}
```

Is there any way I can delete a persistent object using only `colB` value such as

```
 Serializable id = new String(myColBValue);

 Object persistentInstance = session.get(MyObject.class, id);
 if (persistentInstance != null) {
            session.delete(persistentInstance);    
 }
```

or do I have to resort to using HQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you need 2 columns to identify MyObject, then providing just one won't be enough to lookup a unique result every time. Neither `Session` nor `EntityManager` provide the method you're looking for. You'll have to go with `Criteria` or `Query`.

Comment: okay, but how to delete using hql now? PK is a private entity in my entity object. Seems it can't resolve the column. Hibernate 5 is really more trouble than it's work with lack of documentation. session.createQuery("delete from MyObject where PK.colB= :colb")
          .setParameter("colb", "foobar")
          .executeUpdate();  reults in a "could not execute statement" error